# Can a VBA .additem command refer to variable Recordset?

Tags: vba, excel

In the code example below, can the "local_Manufacturer" ADBO.Recordset object somehow be replaced by a variable name?  I've tried to replace it with a string that matches the name of the ADBO.Recordset I want to use, but it gives a compile error stating that the "Qualifier must be a collective".

```
With Me.Controls("Manufacturer")
    .Clear
    Do
        .AddItem local_Manufacturer![Manufacturer]
        local_Manufacturer.MoveNext
        Loop Until local_Manufacturer.EOF
    End With
```

Comment: Do you have multiple recordsets open?  If Yes you could put them in an array and use the array index to specify which one you want.  Or use a Dictionary.

Comment: Really?  Interesting.  You can have an array or dictionary of type ADBO.Recordset in VBA?  Sounds like that could work... let me see.